# jQuery if and statements not working with and

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement

So I had this and it would show the results I needed:

```
if (item.isPrivateToSubOrg == false){
```

and since I've added this it no longer works:

```
if (item.isPrivateToSubOrg == false && item.eventStatus == 'Published'){
```

I'm pulling the data using getJSON and it looks like this:

```
{
auth_result: true,
is_valid: false,
eventId: "80649f4b-437c-4e96-b79e-e02901f33c17",
orgId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
subId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
waiverId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
waiverIdForThisEvent: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
orgName: "",
subName: "",
eventPIN: "",
eventTitle: "",
eventDescr: "",
eventLocation: "",
startUtc: "2050-01-01T00:00:00",
endUtc: "2050-01-01T00:00:00",
startLocal: "2050-01-01T00:00:00",
endLocal: "2050-01-01T00:00:00",
attendanceGoal: 0,
attendanceActual: 0,
eventBudget: 0,
eventCost: 0,
categoryId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
categoryDescr: "",
questionCount: 0,
last_error_msg: "",
attendeeList: [ ],
eventStatusId: "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333",
eventStatus: "Published",
canCheckIn: true,
isPrivateToSubOrg: false,
allowsGuestCheckIn: false,
enteredUserId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
hasImage: false,
twitterID: "",
orgScannerType: "",
rsvpLink: "",
contactPerson: "",
contactEmail: ""
}
```

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you doing this at?

Comment: Based on the data you provided that behavior is impossible: http://jsfiddle.net/g53GA/
Maybe the events you're testing simple aren't "Published" or at least the value is not a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it returns "false" to you, but for me it seems correct and returns "true". See the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZhM3H/

The expression:

```
(item.isPrivateToSubOrg == false && item.eventStatus == 'Published')
```

Returns true when I try it on your sample data. Perhaps the glitch is somewhere else?

Comment: Winner! Yes, this made me rethink and I checked that and realized it was something in our API not updated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean you are trying to compare seems to be the issue. Tried below on jsfiddle:

**Below code works:**

```
var ex = {
    name : "name",
    boolVal : true
};
if (ex.name == "name" && ex.boolVal) {
    console.log("Inside if");
} else {
    console.log("Inside Else");
}
```

**Below Code does not work**

```
var ex = {
    name : "name",
    boolVal : true
};
if (ex.name == "name" && ex.boolVal == true) {
    console.log("Inside if");
} else {
    console.log("Inside Else");
}
```